# Pass data to partial view after it has been loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way that I can pass data to a partial view after it has been rendered. I have a partial view in my _Layout which is rendered. It needs isHeaderShown. However this `isHeaderShown` can only be set after the `@RenderBody` is called because only the body controller has this info.

I have in my layout.

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Index","_Menu", new { area = ""});}

@RenderBody()
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that I can pass data to a partial view after it has been rendered.

Not using server side. You could always make an AJAX request to the server using javascript and then update some portions of the DOM with the results received from the server. This will obviously happen at a later stage after the view has already been rendered in the browser. Another common technique different than AJAX is the server to push some data to the client using HTML5 WebSockets. You can take a look at [`SignalR`](http://www.asp.net/signalr). In both cases you will need to write javascript.